# Web services in C#.Net

Tags: c#, web-services, collections

Hello I am getting an error when I try to run the following code in web service. How to write collections in web services?

```
    [WebMethod]
    public Dictionary<int, string> GetManagers()
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> namesDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AdventureWorksConnectionString"].ConnectionString;


        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(conString))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter("[dbo].[uspGetManagerNames]", connection);
            connection.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sd.Fill(ds);
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {

                    namesDictionary.Add((int)row[0], (string)row["ManagerFirstName"] + (string)row["ManagerLastName"]);
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
            return namesDictionary;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `I am getting an error` what error? why don't you post it, so that we don't have to try to guess it?

Comment: This is the error : The type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] is not supported because it implements IDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The `XmlSerializer` cannot process classes implementing the `IDictionary` interface. The easiest solution would be to return an array of Manager objects instead.